# R: Plot ARC/INFO Generate File

Tags: r, io, ggplot2, polygon

I have an ARC/INFO generate file whose contents look like:

```
3594 -124.049541 44.429077
 -123.381222 44.530192
 -123.479913 44.625517
 -123.578917 44.720704
 -123.678234 44.815755
 -123.777866 44.910669
 -123.946044 44.885032
 -124.114074 44.858987
 -124.281949 44.832529
 -124.449663 44.805654
 -124.516511 44.684660
 -124.583091 44.563597
 -124.649404 44.442465
 -124.715451 44.321261
 -124.615376 44.227772
 -124.515601 44.134147
 -124.416125 44.040385
 -124.316948 43.946486
 -124.151513 43.973082
 -123.985926 43.999247
 -123.820193 44.024987
 -123.654322 44.050307
 -123.586447 44.170362
 -123.518307 44.290360
 -123.449899 44.410303
 -123.381222 44.530192
END
3595 -123.103772 45.009223
 -122.427717 45.101578
 -122.525757 45.198252
 -122.624122 45.294789
 -122.722814 45.391191
 -122.821833 45.487459
 -122.992014 45.464007
 -123.162072 45.440175
 -123.332002 45.415959
 -123.501798 45.391355
 -123.571234 45.271264
 -123.640389 45.151121
 -123.709266 45.030923
 -123.777866 44.910669
 -123.678234 44.815755
 -123.578917 44.720704
 -123.479913 44.625517
 -123.381222 44.530192
 -123.213811 44.554460
 -123.046278 44.578334
 -122.878629 44.601816
 -122.710869 44.624913
 -122.640504 44.744148
 -122.569859 44.863337
 -122.498931 44.982480
 -122.427717 45.101578
END
3676 -122.989567 44.147495
 -122.323040 44.238368
 -122.419523 44.335217
 -122.516322 44.431923
 -122.613437 44.528488
 -122.710869 44.624913
 -122.878629 44.601816
 -123.046278 44.578334
 -123.213811 44.554460
 -123.381222 44.530192
 -123.449899 44.410303
 -123.518307 44.290360
 -123.586447 44.170362
 -123.654322 44.050307
 -123.556277 43.955264
 -123.458534 43.860080
 -123.361093 43.764751
 -123.263953 43.669279
 -123.098838 43.693189
 -122.933613 43.716694
 -122.768285 43.739802
 -122.602857 43.762515
 -122.533309 43.881546
 -122.463492 44.000532
 -122.393403 44.119472
 -122.323040 44.238368
END
END
```

My strategy is to read in the file generating a list of latitude-longitude points and beginning a new unique group id every time I encounter an END. I'll then plot using `ggplot" and`geom_polygon".

Alas, I'm not sure how to efficiently accomplish the reading of the file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Read the spatial task view on CRAN and then use readOGR from the rgdal package to read into an sp class object. You'll need a GDAL/OGR install with ARCGEN format support, which despite being listed as 'compiled by default' [Link](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) I don't have on my system.

Failing that, open the file as a connection, read each line, build a Polygon, then Polygons and SpatialPolygons.

Here's a fairly sub-optimal but working function:

```
readUng <- function(f){
  require(sp)
  stream = file(f,"r")
  first = readLines(stream,1)
  bits = strsplit(first," ")[[1]]
  polys = list();ids=NULL
  while(TRUE){
    id=bits[1] # label pt = bits[2],bits[3]
    ids=c(ids,id)
    coords=NULL
    while(TRUE){
      xy=readLines(stream,1)
      if(xy=="END"){
        break
      }
      coords=rbind(coords,strsplit(xy," ")[[1]])      
    }
    
    polys[[length(polys)+1]] = Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(as.numeric(coords[,2:3]),ncol=2))),ID=id)
    lines = readLines(stream,1)
    if(lines == "END"){
      break
    }
    bits = strsplit(lines," ")[[1]]
  }
  return(SpatialPolygons(polys))
}
```

Now its a proper spatial data object, you can also give it a coordinate system (looks like lat-long to me, so epsg:4326, but only you know). Now you could modify all this to produce whatever ggplot wants, but if its spatial data then you should keep it as a spatial data class and ggplot should be made capable of dealing with such.

Comment: I'm afraid `readOGR` doesn't seem to be working. It complains of being unable to open the file, which is otherwise accessible via other means.

Comment: You probably need to specify the driver. See ogrDrivers() for details. Its the generate or ungenerate driver...

Comment: The ggplot2 package works with data.frames, so building a SpatialPolygons object is not needed.

Comment: Converting from `SpatialPolygons` to `data.frame`s can be done using `fortify`: `poly_df = fortify(poly)`.

Comment: That's bad design. If the map argument to geom_map was anything that can be coerced to whatever internal format geom_map really needs then the user wouldn't need to know about fortify, or map_data, or anything else. Just pass an object and let the OO-machinery sort it out. Then maybe the method for sp-class objects could handle any necessary coordinate transformations...

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, but I'm not sure how to specify the driver.

Comment: With the function I just added, you don't have to! It does it all.